# Access TextView in Fragment throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I am quite new to Android development.

I have a `TextView` in the layout and when I try to access the `TextView` in the `Fragment` class a `NullPointerException` is thrown. I am accessing the TextView as follows...

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quotes);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have looked at other answers regarding this on SO but have not found a solution...

***Relevant Code***

**quotes_details_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quotes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/quotes_details"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**QuotesFragment.java**

```
public class QuotesFragment extends Fragment {

    public QuotesFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.quotes_details_fragment, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quotes); // NullPointerException
        return view;
    }

}
```

(The main activity class is only calling the relevant fragment using `FragmentTransaction`)

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: change this line View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.quotes_details_fragment, container, false);    as View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.quotes_details_fragment, null);

Comment: Thanks @IlangoJ. This worked as well. But why wouldn't it work when  `inflater.inflate(R.layout.quotes_details_fragment, container, false)` is called? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this LayoutInflater in your onCreateView(..);

```
 LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
```

Like this way:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();   

        View view =  lf.inflate(R.layout.quotes_details_fragment, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quotes); // 
        return view;
    }
```